# Why does sort_by change my array elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, gon

I would expect that application of `sort_by` would change the order, but nothing else, about an array.

Here's my original line:

```
gon.frames = @job.sequence.frames.sort_by(&:n)
```

And a modified line, where sort_by is removed:

```
gon.frames = @job.sequence.frames
```

I'm finding that the values in gon.frames (which is transmitted to the browser using the `gon` gem) are different, not just in order, but in how they are converted to strings.

This issue seemed to appear after upgrading to ruby 3.0.0.

Edit: inspecting with Rails console shows that the first line is returning type Array, whereas the second line is returning type  ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.

I am still confused, because this didn't seem to be happening prior to my recent upgrades and change to ruby 3.0.0.

Edit - not sure what the root cause is here, but I rolled back to ruby 2.6.1 and the problem went away.

Edit - I think the change that I experienced may not be related to the type of `frames`. Instead, it could be that `gon` is doing something differently in how it passes this variable to the browser when ruby 3.0.0 is used.

Comment: Are you sure about: "Edit: inspecting with Rails console shows that the first line is returning type ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy, whereas the second line is returning type Array." It would expect it to be the other way round.

Comment: @DavidAldridge you're right, fixed.

Comment: What is `frames` ... an association on `sequence`?

Comment: @DavidAldridge yes, sequence has_many frames.

Comment: GON relies on multi_json, whatever adapter is used by multi_json and its `#dump` as well as the fullness of the moon and the level of the tides. Thats kind of the whole problem of its approach vs using HTTP calls to your own API where you control (and version) the interface between the Ruby and JS world. I wouldn't be suprised if a major ruby version upgrade breaks it.

Comment: @max thanks, I checked out multi_json and it only claims to support up to ruby 2.7. I didn't realize this approach was so flakey.